# how to convert a datetime format to a millisec in python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, dateparser

so python2 does not have datetime.timestamp() is there any way to convert a simple datetime format to epoch like format in other words in milliseconds , or is there any other way to convert the start_date to milliseconds format

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser 

time_interval = "1h"

start_date = dateparser.parse(time.interval)

print (str(start_date))

date_in_millisec = start_date.timestamp()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser 

time_interval = "1h"

start_date = dateparser.parse(time.interval)

print (str(start_date))

date_in_millisec_compared_to_now = datetime.now() - start_date

print (str(date_in_millisec_compared_to_now))
```

Comment: i get an attribute error ( type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute datetime

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I used datetime.datetime while you import datetime. Just change "datetime.datetime.now()" to "datetime.now()" I have updated the answer.